# If I have significant linear and quadratic terms, can I interpret both of these results?

Tags: regression, interpretation, regression-coefficients, quadratic-form

I would have thought there'd be an answer to this question on here already, but I've been unable to find it, so I apologize if this is a repost.

If I have a regression model of the form `Y ~ X + X^2`, and both the `X` and `X^2` terms come back significant, can I safely interpret both of these results? For example, let's say the coefficients for both `X` and `X^2` are significantly positive, would it be appropriate to write something like this: "Y is **significantly** increasing as X increases (interpreting the linear `X` term) at a **significantly** increasing rate (interpreting the quadratic `X^2` term)"?

Comment: Consider them literally as a double act.  They act together. There is no sense in which one can be held constant without the other changing. In any case, why resort to a qualitative verbal summary when you can show the curve? Sometimes the square term is significant yet merely acts to tweak the curvature slightly. Some times the presence of a marked turning point is the main message. You need to plot the curve over the range of the data to see the combined effect; that is immensely more informative than a verbal paraphrase.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304831, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34488, and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28730.  Their answers indicate that $x$ and $x^2$ are usually not interpreted separately and that the interpretation depends on how $x$ is measured.  Consider, then, the reason you are using $x$ and $x^2$, what it means for your model, and what scientific question you are trying to answer.

Comment: While I completely agree with @NickCox, it may be that you are forced by circumstance to be verbal.  In that case, you could write "Y can be modeled as a quadratic function of x", or something similar.

Comment: Great comments all. I believe that I was already inclined to write about them in concert, as you recommend @NickCox. However, the reasoning behind my model is that I am looking for differences in the distributions of responds to a Likert-type survey question between two groups of people (X is binary & categorical) and I have reasons to expect both a rightward shift (linear shift) between the distributions AND a peakedness (quadratic) shift between them as well. My question really is--when can I say I am seeing both?

Comment: I'd consider using e..g. Legendre polynomials instead if it fits.